Is There a Term for the Actual Diagonal (not the Main Diagonal) of a Non-Square Matrix?
I have the following matrix.
\begin{bmatrix}3&4&0&1&0&0&3&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&4&3&1&0&0&3&1\\0&4&0&3&4&0&0&0&3&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&3&0\\0&3&4&0&3&0&0&0&0&0&4\\0&1&0&0&1&1&2&0&0&3&4\end{bmatrix}
I know that, for non-square matrices, the diagonal contains the entries of the matrix where the row and column numbers are equivalent. For this matrix, the diagonal entries would be 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, and 1.
Is there a term that describes a different type of diagonal for non-square matrices, one where the entries fall along the straight line from the upper-left corner to the lower-right corner? For my example matrix, this new diagonal would contain the numbers 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, and 4. These numbers appear on the straight line between the upper-left corner and the lower-right corner.
Thanks!

There may be a diagonal in some way if one of the dimensions divides the other (?), that is $m$ divides $n$, although I don't know the term for it.

It would help users of this site if you wrote the matrix in a mathematical format rather than one depending on a specific programming language.

@orangeskid - yes, although even if the dimensions are not divisible somehow, this diagonal would still exist - it would just be the two values from the upper-left and lower-right corners

If $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then the line segment from the top-left corner to the bottom-right corner of an $m$-by-$n$ matrix does not pass through any other entries of the matrix besides those two endpoints. Otherwise, it will pass through exactly $\gcd(m,n)-1$ entries, excluding the two endpoints.

@GeoffreyTrang - that is all true; I'm just wondering if there's a term for it or if it's ever been described before

This notion of Full Diagonal does not strike me as natural or useful in the the mathematical theory of matrices/linear maps. Did it arise for you in the context of some application? If so, reading more about that particular is probably the best chance of finding an established name.

@ErikT - it's of interest to me because I'm writing code to generate these types of graphs (https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/bipartite/html/plotweb.html) and I want to order the elements of each level such that the resulting figure contains the least amount of crossing links as possible. I have not come across anything in my reading yet.

I have heard of this as being called the 'slant' of the matrix but only in an informal sense.

I do not know any standard name, but it might be possible to call (4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2), for example, the second diagonal.
